# Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got this code from my client iOS app on XCode console

[image]

Firebase registration token: `diWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h
diWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h`

## NodeJS

```
console.log("START");
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
var serverKey = require('/Users/bheng/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/mhn-app-firebase-adminsdk-bs45c-5ac3770488.json')
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey)
var collapseKey = 'new_message';
var message = {
    to: 'diWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h',
    data: {
        cpeMac: '000000000000',
        type: 'malware'
    },
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello baby',
        body: 'Nice body',
        tag: collapseKey,
        icon: 'ic_notification',
        color: '#18d821',
        sound: 'default',
    },
};


fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!")

        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));

    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", JSON.stringify(response))
    }
})

console.log("END");
```

---

## Result

When I run it

```
node app.js
```

I kept getting

```
START                                                                                 
END                                                                                   
Successfully sent with response:  {"results":[{"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-registration-token","message":"Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM."}}],"canonicalRegistrationTokenCount":0,"failureCount":1,"successCount":0,"multicastId":7577724855311354000}
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your token has some additional random string such as 
to: 'diWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h',

just remove : diWY78iar8s: from your token string

```
console.log("START");
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
var serverKey = require('/Users/bheng/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/mhn-app-firebase-adminsdk-bs45c-5ac3770488.json')
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey)
var collapseKey = 'new_message';
var message = {
    to: 'APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h',
    data: {
        cpeMac: '000000000000',
        type: 'malware'
    },
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello baby',
        body: 'Nice body',
        tag: collapseKey,
        icon: 'ic_notification',
        color: '#18d821',
        sound: 'default',
    },
};


fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!")

        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));

    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", JSON.stringify(response))
    }
})

console.log("END");
```

Response from FCM :

```
Successfully sent with response:  { results: [ { messageId: '0:1543448946734425%479ec0e2479ec0e2' } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 0,
  successCount: 1,
  multicastId: 6133765431734591000 }
```

Comment: After removing i am getting invalidServerResponse. Please help mt out.

Answer (score 0):

One of the interesting reasons for invalid registration is: that device have a different token.  Maybe you are trying to use a past token.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what happened was I was getting the FCMRegistrationToken from my colleague via Discord and the Ctrl+C Ctrl+V was modifying the token. On obtaining the token via email solved the issue.